# How to update widget of different size which is of same application?

Tags: android, widget

I'm developing an application it consist of homescreen widget of 3 sizes , my problem is, how to differentiate these 3 types ,

I used on **Broadcast Receiver** class .

public class Receiever extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent) {
    String str = paramIntent.getAction();
    AppWidgetManager localAppWidgetManager = null;
    int[] arrayOfInt = null;

    if ((str.equals("android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED"))
            || (str.equals("android.intent.action.TIME_SET"))
            || (str.equals("com.example.test.UPDATE"))) {
        localAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(paramContext);
        arrayOfInt = localAppWidgetManager
                .getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(paramContext,
                        Provider.class));
        for (int i = 0;; i++) {
            if (i >= arrayOfInt.length) {
                return;
            }

            Provider.updateAppWidget(paramContext, localAppWidgetManager,
                    arrayOfInt[i], "2014-01-01");

        }
    }

}
```

}

and 3 **Provider** classes and 3 **configure** classes , first widget works fine because I'm calling first widget Provider class method in Broadcast Receiver, problem is with other 2 widget , I can create those two size widget but its not updating ..
How can I fix this bug ??